Do UserInfo.getSessionId() is allowed in 2GP Managed Package VF page for calling tooling API?
Context:
We are currently working on AppExchange app development, which requires us to create dynamic trigger on the particular object as part of admin configuration.
On AppExchange configuration screen, admin can select the object do the field mapping and after that they will be shown a screen with trigger code (3 line unmanaged code, which calls the managed package handler), which they can either deploy manually in their existing trigger or they can click on a button called "Deploy to Org".
When they click on "Deploy to org", there is a page (Visualforce Page), which does below things:
VF page contains the code to read the current UserInfo.getSessionId(). VFP is used because UserInfo.getSessionId() from LWC is not API enabled.
Using the session id we are hitting standard REST API '/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger/', to generate a trigger with 3 line of below code
trigger myApp_AccountTrigger on Account (after insert) {
    myApp.handler.triggerHandler();
}

Question:
In above scenario, we are accessing UserInfo.getSessionId() in Apex which is used as a controller in "VFP". In this case, as we are calling UserInfo.getSessionId() from Apex to generate a trigger, as we are generating a trigger by using "UserInfo.getSessionID()", after user consent, will the use of UserInfo.getSessionId() be considered as Security Vulnerability and fail the security review for the AppExchange app? If yes, what can be the alternative approach to generate the dynamic trigger as Admin needs to decide on which object they need to use our application.
We have checked document https://partners.salesforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0684V00000O83jT?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER & under heading 'Which API session ID use cases are allowed?' We have point 'For Metadata API write usage to be approved, you must inform the admin of the changes being made'. As we are showing them code & providing them option we think this should not cause any issue.
NOTE: We asked this question on the security office hours and we have been told that security review team can't comment on this approach. So, we are posting here to check if use of UserInfo.getSessionId() from Apex can fail the security review?
